# Is there a function in Qiskit to measure tensor products of Pauli operators?

Tags: qiskit, programming, q#, pauli-gates, stabilizer-state

Is there a function in Qiskit similar to [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/concepts/pauli-measurements) function in Q# which measures strings of Pauli operators applied to different qubits?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a string of Pauli operators, applied to different qubits, using the `Pauli` class from `qiskit.quantum_info`, and then just do a measurement like you would do for any circuit.

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information ?

Comment: Well I wanted to measure in the eigenbasis of that corresponding Pauli operator. Something like "measure X" equals applying the Hadamard gate and then measure in the computational basis. Just as a preimplemented function in qiskit.

Comment: Sorry for commenting so late. But maybe the [WeightedPauliOperator](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.operators.legacy.WeightedPauliOperator.html) answers your question @sycramore.